# WordPress Default Category and Custom Taxonomy Selected Attribute not Working After Searched in wp_dropdown_categories Array

Tags: categories, taxonomy, search

I have Three Fields in the form, first is Default WordPress Category and two custom taxonomies. When I try to Search a Single field "Selected Attribute" Works Correct but on category, selection taxonomy selected value unselect and do not show selected attribute. Below is the Code:

```
    <form method="get" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>" class="">
    
    
    <!--categories-->   
    <!--default categories dropdown-->
    <?php
    $categoryselected = get_queried_object();
    $categories = wp_dropdown_categories(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'show_option_all' => 'All Categories',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'echo' => 1,
        'select' => $cat,
        'name' => 'cat',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'class' => 'cat-dropdown form-control',
        'id' => 'custom-cat-drop',
        'value_field' => 'term_id',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
       'no_found_rows' => true,
       
       /*when I selected this category other fields selected attributes not working*/
       'selected' => $categoryselected->term_id
    ));
    ?>
    
    <!--location-->
    <?php
    $current_category = get_queried_object();
    wp_dropdown_categories(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'show_option_all' => 'Select Location',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'echo' => 1,
        'name' => 'location',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'class' => 'cat-dropdown form-control',
        'id' => 'custom-cat-dr
        'value_field' => 'name',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
       'no_found_rows' => true,
       

/*in Single Field Search it work correctly but on above category selection attribute not worked*/
       'selected' => $current_category->name
    ));
    ?>
    
    <!--job_type-->
    <?php
    $current_category = get_queried_object();
        wp_dropdown_categories( array(
                        'taxonomy'          => 'job_type',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'show_option_all'  => 'Job Type',
                        'option_none_value' => '',
                        'echo' => 1,
                        'name'              => 'job_type',
                        'id'                => 'custom-cat-drop',
                        'select'          => $cat,
                        'value_field' => 'name',
                        'class' => 'cat-dropdown form-control',
                         'post_status' => 'publish',
                         'hierarchical' => true,
                         'no_found_rows' => true,

/*in Single Field Search it work correctly but on above category selection attribute not worked*/
                          'selected' => $current_category->name
                    ) );
                ?>
    
    <input type="hidden" value="post" name="post_type" />
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn-search">Find Job <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    
    </form>
```

Comment: The `selected` attribute is the same for each of three queries. And it's impossible to say what is its value because it is unknown in which template file the code resides.

Comment: Please Check the Template https://placements.iadm.edu.pk/ and when we search we land on a search template where the selected attribute has not to work.

The above code is created in the template part and applied on Home - Search and other required templates.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have the same `'selected'` parameter for all dropdowns. Secondly, `get_queried_object()` returns different objects in different template files. See User Contributions under [`get_queried_object()` description](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) in the Code Reference.

I've followed the link you've provided, so I suggest to use `get_query_var()`. It's not enough information in the question to suggest something else.

```
<?php

/* Category dropdown */
$category_args = array(
    'selected' => get_query_var('cat'),
    /* Remaining parameters here */
)
wp_dropdown_categories( $category_args );


/* Location dropdown */
$location_args = array(
    'selected' => get_query_var('location'),
    /* Remaining parameters here */
)
wp_dropdown_categories( $location_args );


/* Job Type dropdown */
$job_type_args = array(
    'selected' => get_query_var('job_type'),
    /* Remaining parameters here */
)
wp_dropdown_categories( $job_type_args );
```

Also:

- Check all `wp_dropdown_categories()` arguments as you have a mess there.
- I've added the search values directly to URL and I see wrong search results as the taxonomies are nested in a weird way.

Comment: Great! Working now, very thanks for your Support.

Comment: My pleasure. Please, [mark the answer as accepted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).